# Angular setup with xampp as server

Tags: angularjs, xampp, angular-routing

I'm working on a front-end project which I have wired up with angularjs. In the main page I have an ng-view component and the router basically matches partial routes to different template views with different controllers, as such:

```
/* ... */
myApp.config(function($routeProvider) {        
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: '/pages/01-landing-page.html',
        controller: 'firstCtrl'
    }).
    when('/part2', {
        templateUrl: '/pages/02-second-page.html',
        controller: 'secondCtrl'
    }) 
/* ... */
```

When I run the project from the Adobe Brackets editor which comes with a built-in server all files are loaded properly, including the view pages from the 'templateUrl' attributes.
However when I try to serve the files from XAMPP, the routing seems to get messed up.
Suppose I have the project inside the following directory path: '/xampp/htdocs/proj/proj1'
The main page "index.html" is loaded, however when the angular tries to load the "/pages/01-landing-page.html" the http request for that component is

```
GET myipaddress/pages/01-landing-page.html 404 (Not Found)
```

instead of

```
GET myipaddress/proj/proj1/pages/01-landing-page.html
```

Any idea why angular in this xampp instance seems to ignore the relative path to the project but inside the brackets server it serves everything as it should?

Comment: Your `templateUrl` is an absolute path from the base url `localhost`. Either remove the initial forward slash or define a base href.

Comment: thanks, that was indeed the problem.